# Loading resources locally with PhoneGap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, cordova, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an application for smartphones and tablets with HTML5 and jQuery Mobile, and I want to publish it using PhoneGap. My application is completely web-based. (I'm writing it with Microsoft MVC and C#), which means that my app may also be available via a web address.

But when a smartphone/tablet user opens my app, it is not necessary to load Javascript and CSS remotely. There should be local copies on the user's smartphone/tablet.

So my question is: how to load Javascript and CSS resources locally, while the application is loading remotely?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have it both ways: a Phonegap app is basically a local web site hosted in your smartphone/tablet. Loading a remote web site on PG means either using the ChildBrowser or loading the site into an iframe. So while you could load CSS and JS into the PG app's index.html, it won't be available to the remote web site...

If you are doing a Phonegap app anyway, you should look into doing it in HTML5/CSS/JS, so that everything is local...

Comment: But there is JQuery Mobile and some other plugins which are too heavy. Isn't there anyway to do that even without PhoneGap?

Comment: Nope... I shouldn't think so.